# How can I display more results on a RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, radio-button, richtextbox

I'm a beginner in C# so please be gentle to me .

I'm having a problem trying to display more results in rich text box because it can only display one result at once. But I would like to display the next result when the radio buttons already being resetted and the previous result should also still in the rich text box. Below is my coding:

```
for(int i=0,i<30;i++)
{
  if(symptom1.Checked && symptom2.Checked)
  {
     Result.Text="";
     Result.Text += "Your Disease is: "+"Meningiomas";
  }

  if(symptom7.Checked && symptom8.Checked)
  {
     Result.Text="";
     Result.Text += "Your Disease is: "+"Pituitary Tumor";
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting this **Result.Text="";**. This would erase the previous data, remove it and you should be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to delete the previous content, remove this code:

```
Result.Text="";
```

I think, what you want to achieve is:

1. Clear the RichTextBox
2. Write all matching diseases to the RichTextBox

This can be done with this code:

```
Result.Text="";

for(int i = 0; i < 30; ++i)
{
    if(symptom1.Checked && symptom2.Checked)
    {
        Result.Text += "Your Disease is: "+"Meningiomas";
    }

    if(symptom7.Checked && symptom8.Checked)
    {
        Result.Text += "Your Disease is: "+"Pituitary Tumor";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + "Sample text");
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're only able to display one result at a time is because you *clear* the current contents of the textbox first, before adding the next line. Specifically, this line of code is the culprit:

```
Result.Text="";
```

Since you're setting the `Text` property equal to an empty string (`""`), that clears out whatever is already there, essentially erasing the textbox.

If you simply remove that line from your code, you should see exactly what you want. The next line is appended to whatever is already there. However, this will simply stick it onto whatever is already there.
It won't insert it onto a new line. To do that, you have to insert a line break at the beginning:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
{
   if (symptom1.Checked && symptom2.Checked)
   {
      Result.Text += Environment.NewLine + "Your Disease is: " + "Meningiomas";
   }

   if (symptom7.Checked && symptom8.Checked)
   {
      Result.Text += Environment.NewLine + "Your Disease is: " + "Pituitary Tumor";
   }
}
```

<sub>(Note that `Environment.NewLine` is the same thing as the escape sequences `\r\n`. It just inserts a new line. Same either way.)</sub>

If you want to clear the current contents of the textbox *first*, and then append all the values in your `for` loop, you need to add the line of code back at the *beginning* of the function, before the *for* loop. Stylistically, I would also write it as `string.Empty` rather than `""`, but it doesn't really matter.

```
Result.Text = string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0,i<30;i++)
{
 if(symptom1.Checked && symptom2.Checked)
  {
     //Result.Text=""; remove this
     Result.Text += "Your Disease is: "+"Meningiomas";
  }

if(symptom7.Checked && symptom8.Checked)
{
     //Result.Text=""; remove this
     Result.Text += "Your Disease is: "+"Pituitary Tumor";
}
}
```

Result.Text=""; is causing your existing data to be replaced by an empty text, remove that and you should be fine with your results.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a poor unfortunate might have syptoms 1, 2, 7, and 8; and therefore probably has two types of tumor at once:

```
for(int i=0,i<30;i++) {
  Result.Text="Your Disease is:";
  if(symptom1.Checked && symptom2.Checked) {
     Result.Text += " Meningiomas";
  }
  if ( symptom7.Checked && symptom8.Checked ) {
     Result.Text += " Pituitary Tumor";
  }
}
```

Cheers. Keith.

PS: Your question really isn't very clear.